# how to use urlmon.h DownloadProgressCallback in C language, not c++

Tags: c, urlmon

I hope make progress bar to urlmon in C. but it wasn't work
I don't know what the problem is.
If there's another way to download the URL and receive download progress, I will give that a try
and if this question messed. please inform me, i Modify this question

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <urlmon.h>

// 진행 상황 콜백 함수
void DownloadProgressCallback(
    ULONG ulProgress,
    ULONG ulProgressMax) {
}

int main() {
    HRESULT hr;
    LPCWSTR url = L"LINK";
    LPCWSTR localFileName = L"C:/Temp/test.zip";

    // 진행 상황 콜백을 사용하여 다운로드
    hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url, localFileName, 0, DownloadProgressCallback);

    if (hr == S_OK) {
        wprintf(L"\nDownload completed successfully.\n");
    }
    else {
        wprintf(L"\nDownload failed with error code: 0x%08X\n", hr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result
"Thread 0x4754 has exited (code: 0x0).
Exception thrown (0x00007FFC2A1045CF in urlmon.dll, TestURL.exe): 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF."

Comment: Have you run your program with a debugger?  It'll probably stop on the exact link that's giving you a problem.

Comment: Sorry for not providing additional information earlier. I've changed the URL to my personal information to LINK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot.

The last expected parameter is a pointer to an object implementing the `IBindStatusCallback` interface that only C++ can provide. Your error reveals that the called `URLDownloadToFile()` tries to dereference the given pointer, and fails for sure.

As a solution you can provide a small C++ class implementing that interface, and use an instance of this class to call your C callback. However, since you don't want to use C++, I did not prepare an example.

Comment: thanks, So never use IBindStatusCallback in C. if use this, must C++, not C.
right?

Comment: @Mediblo **Correct** ... well, in principle. _If_ you are a C/C++ wizard, and _if_ you know what you are doing, and _if_ you know how the underlying mechanism works, and _if_ you have an intimate knowledge in the used compiler, and _if_ you are sure that your code is always checked before compiling with a new compiler, and _if_ you are sure that your code is always checked before compiling for a new system, and _if_ you accept breaking several rules, _then_ you might be able to provide a C structure that resembles the expected object. But I'm sure that you shall and will not go that way.

Comment: sorry for the late comment, and thanks comment. I probably won't use IBindStatusCallback because my C language skills may not be sufficient.